# Have Directory.GetFiles return one file at a time? (.NET)

Tags: .net, directory, getfiles

I have a folder with far too many files in, and I want to go through each file one by one. The problem is that Directory.GetFiles returns a completed array, and this takes too long.

I would rather have an object I would point to a folder, then call a function that returns me the next file in the folder. Does .NET have a class like this please?

(I'd prefer to avoid win32 interops, as I plan to use this on Mono as well.)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this in .NET 3.5, but you can in .NET 4.0, [as per this blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee428166.aspx):

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\share\symbols");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = directory.EnumerateFiles();
foreach (var file in files) {
    Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, Length={1}", file.Name, file.Length);
}
```

(Likewise there's a static [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(VS.100).aspx) method.)

I don't know whether that API has been ported to Mono yet.

Comment: just a question, why not use: var files = directory.EnumerateFiles(); ?

Comment: @Filip: I don't know about Jon's reasons, but I would use the type name for clarity since it is not obvious from the method name what type it returns.

Comment: @Fredrik, isn't it clear enough that it is going to return an enumeratable file info list? The Method-name is really self-explaining. The same goes for DirectoryInfo, i would rather use var directory =... I know that there is a difference at compile time though.

Comment: @Fredrik: That example is copied directly from the referenced blog post.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something that would work in .NET 2, but if it's not there, it's not there.  
(That's the second rule of Tuatology Club.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [FastDirectoryEnumerator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/FastDirectoryEnumerator.aspx?msg=3177659) project on CodeProject web site.

It does exactly what you need and even more, I was able to successfully use it on a slow network share with lots of files and performance was just great.

Drawback - it uses interop so it may not be portable to Mono.

Comment: Thanks, I may end up using that, but falling back to Directory.GetFiles if it throws an interop exception, indicating that I'm probably not on win32.

Comment: You can use `Environment.OSVersion` to determine if you are running under Windows or not and find some other code that will work fast on the operating system you are targeting.